# How do I call a web API from Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to do a HTTP GET using Blazer, but I am unsure how.

This is how I would do it in .NET

```
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

class CoinMarketCapAPI
{
    private static string API_KEY = "___";

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(makeAPICall());
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    static string makeAPICall()
    {
        var URL = new UriBuilder("https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest");

        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        queryString["start"] = "1";
        queryString["limit"] = "5000";
        queryString["convert"] = "USD";

        URL.Query = queryString.ToString();

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY", API_KEY);
        client.Headers.Add("Accepts", "application/json");
        return client.DownloadString(URL.ToString());

    }

}
```

From this code that is working in a console, I want to fetch the data in Blazor.
It is data of cryptocurrency.
I want to use Blazor for the web front-end.

I write this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;


namespace Cryptonite.API
{

    public class CoinMarketCapAPI : ReadAPI

    {
        
        
        private static string API_KEY = "";

        public bool IsSupported(string symbol)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public CoinMarketCapAPI()
        {
            baseUrl = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/";

        }
        public override string Request(string tail)
        {
           
            var URL = new UriBuilder(baseUrl + tail);

            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
            queryString["start"] = "1";
            queryString["limit"] = "5000";
            queryString["convert"] = "USD";

            URL.Query = queryString.ToString();

            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY", API_KEY);
 
            return client.DownloadString(URL.ToString());

        }

        

        public class Crypto_listings
        {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        }
    
        public async Task<List<Crypto_listings>> GetCryptoList()
        {
        string json = Request("cryptocurrency/listings/latest");
        return await Parse<List<Crypto_listings>>(json);
        }

       
    }

    }
```

I try to rewrite the code for Blazor.
My code isn't running at all.
I made test for the tail of the url but noting work.
It is my .cs file.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server
"A Blazor Server app doesn't include an HttpClient service by default. Provide an HttpClient to the app using the HttpClient factory infrastructure."

Comment: What happens when you put this code in a Blazor app?

Comment: Is this blazor server, or blazor webassembly?

Comment: I used blazor server

Comment: If you're using Blazor server the API call is made _from the server_ - so any REST-based client will work. If your code worked in a console app it should work in the ASP.NET Core server. I generally use [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/). A good approach is to split different parts of the app into testable components. Maybe a library called CoinMarketCapAPI. You can write unit tests that prove this library works, the use it in your Blazor app. If it doesn't work there the problem is easier to track down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what works for me every time, for any HTTP/SOAP or HTTP/REST API consumption from Blazor, read the code comments for clarity and how to modify to suit your requirement.

```
string payloadText = string.Empty; /* Your payload string (XML/JSON) */
Uri url = new Uri("https://yourapiurl.com");
CredentialCache userCreds = new();
userCreds.Add(url, "Basic", new NetworkCredential("username","password"));
try
{
    byte[] payload = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payloadText);
    /* Prepare HTTPWebRequest ****************************************************************************************************/
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
    httpRequest.Credentials = userCreds;
    httpRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpRequest.Accept = "*/*";
    httpRequest.ContentType = "application/soap+xml"; /* Change to what's needed for the API, could be application/json etc. */
    httpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
    httpRequest.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
    httpRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
    httpRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(payload, 0, payload.Length);
    /* Execute HTTPWebRequest ****************************************************************************************************/
    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
    string responseString = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    /* Response is a C# class object modeled as per expected response XML */
    /* Good tool to create C# objects: https://json2csharp.com/ */
    response = XDocument.Parse(responseString);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    /* Error Handling or Logging Code as needed goes here */
    throw;
}
```

**Update for .NET CORE 6:**
You will start getting a compile warning when targeting .NET 6 as follows: *'WebRequest.Create(string)' is obsolete: 'WebRequest, HttpWebRequest, ServicePoint, and WebClient are obsolete. Use HttpClient instead.'*. Here is the translation of above code to HTTPClient:

```
/* Setting up the Client */
string payloadText = string.Empty; // Your payload string (XML/JSON)
HttpClient client = new();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://yourapiurl.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password")));

/* Setting up Request - Notice that "Content-Type" is getting set here */
HttpRequestMessage req = new();
req.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
req.Content = new StringContent(payloadText, Encoding.UTF8, "application/soap+xml");

/* Call the API and parse the Response */
HttpResponseMessage resp = new();
resp = await client.SendAsync(req);
string resptext = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```